# NumPy配列の各要素にカンマを付けて出力する方法

Tags: python, python3, numpy

例えば、(6,6)の次の配列の出力を

```
[[ 0.0000  0.3505 -0.6385  0.6240 -0.3382  0.0111]
 [ 0.3505  1.2691  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.3503]
 [-0.6385  0.0000  0.7116  0.0000  0.0000  0.6385]
 [ 0.6240  0.0000  0.0000 -0.7621  0.0000  0.6240]
 [-0.3382  0.0000  0.0000  0.0000 -1.2549  0.3380]
 [ 0.0111  0.3503  0.6385  0.6240  0.3380  0.0000]]
```

次のように各要素にカンマを付けて出力する方法を教えてください。

```
[[ 0.0000,  0.3505, -0.6385,  0.6240, -0.3382,  0.0111]
 [ 0.3505,  1.2691,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.3503]
 [-0.6385,  0.0000,  0.7116,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.6385]
 [ 0.6240,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.7621,  0.0000,  0.6240]
 [-0.3382,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -1.2549,  0.3380]
 [ 0.0111,  0.3503,  0.6385,  0.6240,  0.3380,  0.0000]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.array2string](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html) でカンマ区切りの文字列にできますが，すべての要素についてしまいます．

厳密に出力例のようにするのであれば，効率的ではないですが例えば下のような関数でできます．

```
import numpy as np

ary = np.array([
    [ 0.0000,  0.3505, -0.6385,  0.6240, -0.3382,  0.0111],
    [ 0.3505,  1.2691,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.3503],
    [-0.6385,  0.0000,  0.7116,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.6385],
    [ 0.6240,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.7621,  0.0000,  0.6240],
    [-0.3382,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -1.2549,  0.3380],
    [ 0.0111,  0.3503,  0.6385,  0.6240,  0.3380,  0.0000]])

print(np.array2string(ary, separator=', ', formatter={'float_kind': lambda x: '{: .4f}'.format(x)}))

# [[ 0.0000,  0.3505, -0.6385,  0.6240, -0.3382,  0.0111],
#  [ 0.3505,  1.2691,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.3503],
#  [-0.6385,  0.0000,  0.7116,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.6385],
#  [ 0.6240,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.7621,  0.0000,  0.6240],
#  [-0.3382,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -1.2549,  0.3380],
#  [ 0.0111,  0.3503,  0.6385,  0.6240,  0.3380,  0.0000]]

def format_array(ary):
    n = len(ary) - 1
    ret = "["
    for i, x in enumerate(ary):
        if i != 0:
            ret += ' '
        ret += '['
        ret += ', '.join(['{: .4f}'.format(xx) for xx in x])
        ret += ']'
        if i != n:
            ret += '\n'
    ret += ']'
    return ret

print(format_array(ary))

# [[ 0.0000,  0.3505, -0.6385,  0.6240, -0.3382,  0.0111]
#  [ 0.3505,  1.2691,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.3503]
#  [-0.6385,  0.0000,  0.7116,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.6385]
#  [ 0.6240,  0.0000,  0.0000, -0.7621,  0.0000,  0.6240]
#  [-0.3382,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, -1.2549,  0.3380]
#  [ 0.0111,  0.3503,  0.6385,  0.6240,  0.3380,  0.0000]]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。解決しました。